# how to reference classes from other package in Android?

Tags: android

I'd like to ask how to reference other classes from my other package in Android?

I have my main package. Under that it has several subpackages.
How do I reference those classes under subpackage into my main class in the main package?

What I'm doing is, in the main class, I'm calling the class in the subpackage via Intent.
Here's what I've tried so far to no avail:

```
case 0:
        Intent acorn = new Intent( "com.fps.iHealthFirst.vegetables.AcornSquash.class" );
        //Intent acorn = new Intent( Nutritional_List.this, AcornSquash.class );
        startActivity( acorn );
        break;
```

I'm having a hard time doing this. Thanks for your help.

BTW, this is the logcat:

```
10-22 23:13:03.585: E/AndroidRuntime(395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 23:13:03.585: E/AndroidRuntime(395): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.fps.iHealthFirst/com.fps.iHealthFirst.vegetables.AcornSquash}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Also, I've edited this in the manifest file:

```
    <activity android:exported="false"
        android:name=".vegetables.AcornSquashAcornSquash"
        android:label="@string/inutrition" >
        <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.fps.iHealthFirst.vegetables.ACORNSQUASH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

```
    import com.fps.iHealthFirst.vegetables.AcornSquash;

    Intent acorn = new Intent(this, AcornSquash.class);
    startActivity(acorn);
```

UPDATE:

You have to declare all your activities in your Manifest.xml. Keep it simple:

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.fps.iHealthFirst.vegetables.AcornSquash"
        android:label="@string/some_name" >
    </activity>
```

Finally, make sure your folder structure is in line with your packages paths, i.e. your file `AcornSquash.java` has to be in the `src/com/fps/iHealthFirst/vegetables/` folder.

Comment: Okay, how about including .* ? Coz I have many classes I want to reference into the main class?

Comment: I am not a big fan of .* includes because it is not explicit enough, but if you have to you can use this type of import: `import com.fps.iHealthFirst.*`

Comment: <activity android:exported="false"
            android:name="com.fps.iHealthFirst.vegetables.AcornSquashAcornSquash"
            android:label="@string/inutrition" >
            <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.fps.iHealthFirst.vegetables.ACORNSQUASH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

Intent acorn = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "com.fps.iHealthFirst.vegetables.AcornSquash" );

Comment: hey thanks. How about setting something in the androidmanifest file?

Comment: <activity ...>
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>  do you understand this?

Comment: sorry what's that for? Im newbie

Comment: I tried your solution above but eclipse says remove argument to match Intent(string)?

Comment: this is action like define main activity in manifest, now open your manifest, look for main action, action view like this, i'll hope you understand

Comment: Yes, I tried something please see my update post above. thanks.